# Running Browsersync alongside debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've got a fairly specific use case, and I just can't get it to work in vscode. Any help appreciated :)

I am using vscode with live share to work on a webapp with some friends, and I'm trying to get the debugger working nicely. I'm using Browsersync so that my friends can also view the live-updating site

The ideal would be:

1. Press [Debug: Start Debugging]
2. A task is started in a vscode containing browsersync, started using my config file
3. Chrome starts/gets new tabs, opening the development site & the browsersync UI
4. VSCode's debugger attaches to the chrome tab containing the webapp
5. [Debugging ensues]
6. Done debugging, click [Debug: Stop]
7. The dev site & BS UI tabs close
8. VSCode detaches from chrome
9. Browsersync shuts down

**My config atm**

My Start menu chrome shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "BSStart",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "config/BSStart.bat",
        }
    ]
}
```

BSStart.bat

```
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" [dev URL]
start browser-sync.cmd start -c .\config\bs-config.js
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to url with files served from ./out",
            "preLaunchTask": "BSStart",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "url": "[dev URL]",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem with this config being that browsersync is opened in a new window, and it doesn't close once the debugging is done. Is there any way to get it working the way I want?